# customize the record detail page with custom lightning in Community

Tags: community, community-builder

is there any way to add a tab after Detail & Related Tabs in Record details at community builde , if yes, i want add my custom lightning component in the new tab after detail & Related Tab.

Thank in Advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add. Just remove out of the box Detail and Related component.Once you have freed the space, now from components palette drag and drop **Tabs** into the emptied space. Create tabs 1.Detail 2.Related 3.your custom.

In Detail tab you can drag and drop Record Detail, In Related tab you can drag and drop Related List and the custom component in the 3rd tab.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant alter the components that are provided ootb through the builder, you will have to [build your own](https://www.google.ca/search?q=build%20lightning%20component%20for%20communities&rlz=1C1GCEU_frCA820CA820&oq=build%20lightning%20component%20for%20communities&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5682j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: you mean new lightning component for entire Detail page with all tabs? if yes. how to redirect to my custom new Lightning component details page from standard list view  column link click?

Comment: you can simply drag and drop a tabs component, and within it add the components that already exist, alongisde your own component as mentioned by @steamyfire